# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: nonce too low

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, javascript, nodejs, ropsten

I am trying to deploy some contracts on Ropsten network. **Here is my code**

```
async function finalDeploy(r){

  for(i=0; i<constructorParams.length; i++) {

    const options = {
      data: '0x' + myBin[r]+constructorParams[i],
      gas: 5000000,
  };
  const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey1);
  const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction); // here error occured 
  console.log("Contract: " +r+" is deployed at  " +receipt.contractAddress);
  contractAddressess.push(receipt.contractAddress)

  }

}
```

The above code is working perfectly on Ganache UI, but when i changed its provider from localhost to `Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/7fb0bdc97cbe419...");`  then **i am receiving this error ;**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: nonce too low
    at Object.ErrorResponse (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:29:16)
    at C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:140:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:102:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:3816) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3816) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Run it again (more generally, run it in a `try`/`catch` block until success).

Comment: i do it in try / catch.. but same not deployed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it again.

More generally, run it inside a `try`/`catch` block until success.

For your specific error, it is possible that the node is not synchronized with your account's current nonce, so you may want to add this to your `options` object:

```
nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(0xYourAccountAddress)
```

Since you may also encounter other types of errors, I suggest that you try this:

```
async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, account, data, gas) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account.address),
                data: "0x" + data,
                gas: gas
            };
            const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function finalDeploy(r) {
    const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey1);
    for (let i = 0; i < constructorParams.length; i++) {
        const receipt = await send(web3, account, myBin[r] + constructorParams[i], 5000000);
        console.log("Contract: " + r + " is deployed at " + receipt.contractAddress);
        contractAddressess.push(receipt.contractAddress)
    }
}
```

Comment: i could not see that the how above functions are related and called through my finalDeploy function .... ?

Comment: @AmirAli: Did you scroll the code down? It's there.

Comment: sorry , i got it that code .... but still same issue ,..Returned error: nonce too low
Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry:

Comment: @AmirAli: You have a transaction with low price "stuck" in the network. Add `gasPrice: Some higher price` to the `options` object in order to get rid of that.

Comment: @AmirAli: Also, what is your account address? I can have a look into the last transaction of it on ropsten.

Comment: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x71823a8134e8f57885ac8b2925c8ff49ab678ad9... my ID : 0x71823A8134E8f57885AC8b2925C8fF49Ab678ad9

Comment: @AmirAli: Try to add `nonce: 7` to the `options` object.

Comment: yes, it works... but it seem to be awkward ... i have to manage and track all nonce related actions (for setters functions, creating further contracts .... )

Comment: is there any automatic way to generate the nonces

Comment: @AmirAli: Yes - `await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(0xYourAccountAddress)`. But if you don't set the nonce at all, then web3 uses this value implicitly (AFAIK). That's why I did not bother to suggest that as a possible solution. Oh well... maybe that's not the case, so try adding `nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(0xYourAccountAddress)` to your `options` object.

Comment: yes, now it works .. please update your answer, so that i could accept it and will be benefit for community ...

Comment: however, my other methods does'nt work.. like getter / setter , where I have used sendTransaction({from:account1,  to:myContAddr,  data: mydata}).... I think , i must have to post another question for my getter/setter ... ?

Comment: @AmirAli: Done. Please note that I have updated function `send` (and subsequently function `finalDeploy`) to be more generalized.

Comment: when i called my getter functions .. this error comes The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Comment: @AmirAli: Not sure what getters and setters you're asking about, but calling getters doesn't require singing and/or sending a transaction to begin with. You just need to call the function and then do whatever you wanna do with the returned value.